# arm lost kilobyte on compilation

Tags: c, makefile, embedded, arm, contiki

For starters, I'm not an embedded engineer but I developed in C for a few years.
My problem: when I compile the source code from one of our embedded software (based on contiki) on my laptop, I get a different file size (222Kb 236Kb against) than our subcontractor delivered (I can not contact) . And I do not know why I have this difference.
I want to study tracks.
- I have good library
- I use the same ARM EABI compiler
- I use the same makefile
I have installed the same compiler ARM EABI than our subcontractor, so I think (perhaps wrongly) that my output is ready for embedded. I'm wrong?

Ideas?

Comment: what file format are these files you are comparing?

Comment: i comparing the .hex files

Answer (score 1):

That could be down to a number of things such as:

- Different compiler version
- Different target processor
- Different compiler options (especially optimisation and debug options).
- Different library code linked (standard library or third-party).
- Different build configuration (by command-line macros definitions for example).

Answer (score 0):

With every compiler\linker you can always find the map by sections like this:

```
 text       data        bss        dec        hex    filename 
 0x1408     0x18      0x81c       7228       1c3c    size.elf
```

Compare these sections one by one for both building environments to narrow down subject of investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask your subcontractor to provide the map file and compare the map file with the one on your side.

Add `-Wl,-Map=the_map.map` to LFLAGS if you are using GCC.

P.S. More over, make sure you have the same configuration. For example, if your subcontractor did a "release" build, you should compare with your own "release" build as well.